# Railsで自分自身のControllerに対してリダイレクトをする方法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

なんらかの理由で、あるコントローラーにアクセスされたら、それ自身に対してリダイレクトする処理を挟みたいとします。具体的にいうと、`/foo`から、何らかの処理を加えて、`/foo`へのリダイレクトを行うという形です。

この時、他のコントーラーでも似たような処理を行いため、自分自身に対してリダイレクトするように、共通の処理として切り出したほうが望ましいかと思うので、例として下のようなメソッドとして切り出しました:

```
def self_redirect
  # do anything ...
  return redirect_to :action => params["action"], :controller => params["controller"]
end
```

ですが、わざわざ`params`を見にいくのも変な気がします。もっとよりよい書き方はあるのでしょうか? それともこの用途に便利なメソッドがあったりするのでしょうか?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`redirect_to request.original_url` で現在のURLにリダイレクトできるはずです。